Multiagent reinforcement learning
I am trying to apply or replicate a reinforcement learning problem for the following problem. Could you please suggest some basic algorithm as well as resources.
In a 7×7 grid there are two agents and two objects. There is a house too in that grid.The job of both agents is to pick each of the object  and put in the located house. Does independent q learning work nice or is there a common  shared q learning algorithm for both agents to achieve such goals. I also want the agents not to collide before picking the objects or after picking the object.
I would be grateful  if you could provide me some resources or articles in explaining how the goal is achieved by q learning approach or any multiagent reinforcement machine learning. I don't want to apply deep reinforcement learning for now.

Why do you need two agents since they are performing the same task? Why not learn the value function for just one agent and apply it to both tasks?
